# How do I detected a logged in user outside of Handlebars templates when using Ember Simple Auth?

Tags: ember.js

If I want to test for authorisation in a template, I can check `session.isAuthenticated`. How do I do that in JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The session is injected into all routes, controllers, models and views. Thus you can always access it with

```
this.get('session')
```

Authentication status can be accessed via

```
this.get('session.isAuthenticated')
```

Also see https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/blob/master/packages/ember-simple-auth/lib/mixins/authenticated_route_mixin.js#L33 for an example.